# Pass a variable as an import_playbook variable

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to prompt for a password in a parent playbook and then pass that variable to children playbooks imported with *import_playbook*. When I run it, I receive the following error. Is it possible to pass variables in this way? I was able to get around this by using *extra_vars* instead.

> ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2
> block or quotes: child_playbook.yaml password="{{ parentVar }}""

Parent Playbook

```yaml
    - hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
      connection: local
    
      vars_prompt:
        - name: parentVar
          prompt: "Enter parent var"
    
      tasks:
        - debug:
            var: parentVar
    
    - name: 'import child playbook'
      import_playbook: child.yaml childVar="{{ parentVar }}""
```

Child Playbook

```yaml
    ---
    - hosts: localhost
      connection: local
    
      tasks:
    
        - debug:
            var: childVar
```

The reason for using *import_playbook* vs *include_tasks* is to be able to run the playbooks independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(updated with Ansible 2.14)

Q: ***"Is it possible to pass variables in this way?"***

A: No. It's not possible. [*import_playbook*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html#ansible-builtin-import-playbook-module-import-a-playbook) including the *vars* in the scope of this import is evaluated before the playbook starts. The variable *parentVar* doesn't exist at this point. As a result, you should see

```yaml
  childVar: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

---

Note: The error you see is the result of the syntax error (the unbalanced quotes)

```yaml
  import_playbook: child.yaml childVar="{{ parentVar }}""
```

---

You can test it by setting the default value of the variable *childVar*. The plays

```yaml
shell> cat child.yaml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: childVar
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: parentVar
      prompt: "Enter parent var"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: parentVar

- name: Import child playbook
  import_playbook: child.yaml
  vars:
    childVar: "{{ parentVar|d('default') }}"
```

always give

```yaml
  childVar: default
```

The extra variable works because it is available before the playbook starts

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e parentVar=ext_var pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  parentVar: ext_var

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  childVar: ext_var

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

[Note](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_prompts.html): Prompts for individual *vars_prompt* variables will be skipped for any variable that is already defined through the command line *--extra-vars* option ...

---

The solution would be to 'instantiate' the variable *childVar* in the first play. This way the variable *childVar* would be available via [*hostvars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts) in the scope of the whole playbook to all hosts from the first play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: parentVar
      prompt: "Enter parent var"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: parentVar
    - set_fact:
        childVar: "{{ parentVar }}"
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.localhost.childVar

- name: Import child playbook
  import_playbook: child.yaml
  vars:
    childVar: "{{ parentVar|d('default') }}"
```

gives (provided the value *prompt_var* at the [prompt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_prompts.html#interactive-input-prompts) *Enter parent var:*)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 
Enter parent var: 

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  parentVar: prompt_var

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  hostvars.localhost.childVar: prompt_var

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  childVar: prompt_var

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```